# how to get the font-style from the psd file using PS script

Tags: photoshop-script

right now I want to get the font-style from the PSD file using
the Photoshop script, but I fail.

Answer (score 2):

By font style do you mean italic, bold etc? You can pull up the font name using this:

```
for (var i = app.activeDocument.layers.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  var tempLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers[i]

  if (tempLayer.kind == 'LayerKind.TEXT')
  {
    var textContents = tempLayer.textItem.contents;
    var fontSize = tempLayer.textItem.size;
    var fontFace = tempLayer.textItem.font;
    alert (fontFace)
    -- will return something like Arial MT Bold
  }
}
```

You might want to look at this post as well
[PS text contents](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4660&sid=b2cf95f95ea6c877d73caef543e3346b)